# Avoiding LSP (Liskov Substitution Principles) violations

Tags: software-design, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm currently reading the ["Working Effectively with Legacy Code" by Michael Feathers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)

and I think I understand about the LSP violations, but the thing is it says something about the rules of thumb that help avoiding LSP violations which are,

> 1. Whenever possible, avoid overriding concrete methods.
> 2. If you do, see if you can call the method you are overriding in the overriding method.

I don't quite understand the number 2, could you help me clarify this please ?

Answer (score 2):

I think, is the meaning:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void MyFunc()
    {
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void MyFunc()
    {
        base.MyFunc();
    }
}
```